# error when building an iOS app, with apple LLVM 4.1

Tags: ios, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an old MetroWerks CodeWarrior (that's what the `__MWEKRS__` macro signifies) include directory in your search path. Did you import this project from an old CodeWarrior project ? Or did you inadvertently add an inappropriate directory somehow ? Look at the build commands being generated, in particular at what `-I` directives are being emitted.